# How to mass render differently scaled shape in webgl?

Tags: javascript, performance, opengl-es, webgl

I'm trying to render a bunch of trees that are all different sizes composed of two cubes (one for the leaves and one for the trunk). 
If I create a vertex buffer for each tree, bind the buffer, and make a call to draw for each individual tree, the program will slow down immensely.

I faced a similar problem for terrain and solved it as follows:
Generate all the terrain at the beginning, place all vertices in a huge position buffer, and send the entire buffer to be drawn at once. This made the program run way faster than when I was sending each triangle of the terrain individually.

However, this process can't really be applied to the trees, because the number of trees is continuously changing (some die and some are born in each turn. They also grow in size as they get older, from a sapling to a huge oak). 
This means I would have to remake the huge position buffer each frame, which is impractical.

Is there a way I could use the same position buffer for each tree, but just scale it differently? Maybe in the shader (I'm woefully confused by the code in the shader)? 
If such a thing is possible, could it also be used to translate and rotate the same shape many times? If so, then I could apply that to how my terrain is rendered, making terraforming possible (if I tried to do that now then I'd have to remake the terrain vertex position buffer each frame terraforming is taking place, which is way too slow).

One constraint is that I do not want to use three.js. I rewrote my whole program using three.js and it was much, much slower, and much uglier since the way I was previously using textures couldn't be used with three.js. I would really appreciate an answer that sticks with just the baseline webgl and javascript, since it leaves me with more control over optimizing my final code.

Comment: http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html

Comment: You need to write a bit of memory managing code. First, create one big buffer that stores all your tree data, but for each tree, it need to know where the start/index of its own data is and how big its own data is. Then, whenever you need to reflect change to a single tree, use gl.bufferSubData to make the specific change to those trees that requires changing. The second solution is to use one mesh for tree and sent a different transformation matrix for each tree via uniform.